# Resizing to fit an Image in a TableView Cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I`m using an Image that is 320x30 using this code :

```
UIImageView *bg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"higlight_cell_mockup.png"]];
[bg setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
cell.backgroundView = bg ;
```

Problem is, it's still looking like this :
[image]

instead of scaling the image up to fill the cell .

Any ideas ?

---

**Edit**

This is using :

```
[bg setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
```

[image]

And this is using :

```
[bg setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
```

[image]

They vertically scale up better but they BG is still only filling a tiny portion of the cell left of the text, can't get it to fill the entire cell unfortunately ..

Answer (score 0):

Try to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196055/how-to-resize-image-comming-from-xml-feed/3196247#3196247) sort of resizing which might solve your problem

Comment: hmm, getting : warning: 'UIImageView' may not respond to '-drawInRect:'

Comment: dont apply it on uiimageview it is for uiimage please understand the code.

Comment: But something I find weird, is why would I see just a few pixels by default instead of seeing the full image even if it's not filling the cell ?

Comment: If you want it to fill the cell you should use aspect fill or scale to fill, not aspect fit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried your latest solution together with `cell.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];` ? I think it will work.